# Django function reverse() causing MemoryError when under apache/mod_wsgi

Tags: python, django, centos

Django function reverse() causing MemoryError here is actual view below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def index(request):
  return HttpResponse(reverse('main-page')) #display the link of main-page
```

This error occurs only when running under apache/mod_wsgi. I am using

```
Apache/2.2.15 
mod_wsgi/3.5 
Python/2.7.7 
Django/1.5.8
OS/CentOS 6.5
```

Additional Info: This error occurs only when deploying in our online server. There was no error running in our local dev server.

Comment: this feels like a memory error, like the `main-page` regex is confused.  What is your `urls.py`?

Comment: url(r'^$', 'apps.intent.base.views.base.index', name='main-page')

Comment: running under manage.py runserver is fine. But this only occurs when using apache/mod_wsgi

Comment: Only time I have seen a strange MemoryError pop up in mod_wsgi use was due to some SELinux issues. So try temporarily disabling SELinux extensions. Here is one example of where it would cause problems. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=582009

Comment: Yup! solve this issue **setsebool httpd_tmp_exec on**